# I'm confused with the use of 'than'

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with the use of 'than' in this sentence. Please explain it to me.

> Your philosophy of life is different than mine.

Comment: 'than' is being used as a comparator here, comparing the subject's philosophy to someone else's. This is more common in US English; in British English, we'd usually say "Your philosophy of life is different to mine."

Comment: @ialarmedalien - I'm just one data point, but this American would be more likely to use _different from mine_, as opposed to _different than mine_. (I wouldn't have a problem with the latter, though.)

Answer (score 2):

The word **than** is used in comparative constructions. Its complement, in your sentence **mine**, is one of the comparands.

> Our car is older than their car.
>
> Our car is older than theirs.

With **different** you will encounter **from** and **than**, and also **to** [now and then](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=different%20to%2Cdifferent%20than%2C%20different%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20from%3B%2Cc0).

> Our car is different from|than|to theirs. Ours is AWD with a CVT and theirs is
>   a standard transmission with front-wheel drive, but otherwise they look identical.

Comment: GloWbE results for [`different from|to|than`](https://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=67461436) and [`different from|to|than mine`](https://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=67461340).

Comment: @userr2684291:  I distrust  corpora based on web pages for a number of reasons.

Comment: That's fair, but everything there is clickable and you can see it in context. You can't do that with Google Books with most of the results. In my experience, results given by GloWbE are fairly accurate; more accurate than the Google Books Ngram Viewer chart because from what I see it uses both BrE and AmE data, and even when you separate it into BrE and AmE corpora, you still get results which don't exactly align with GloWbE **or** [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=67461962).

Comment: Agreed, the US vs British feature in Google is shite.